# java.lang.NoSuchMethodErrror:'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to use flapdoodle embedded mongodb for writing the unit tests. But I was receiving the following error. "java.lang.NoSuchMethodErrror:'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder
com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(int)"

Is there any dependency I need to add here ? Is the code which I have written in @Before block correct. At the end I need MongoClient and MongoDatabse to pass to other method and test.

```
**MongoDBConfig file:**


import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoDBConfig {
    @Value("${mongo.db.url}")
    private String MONGO_DB_URL;

    @Value(("${mongo.db.port:27017}"))
    private int MONGO_DB_PORT;

    @Value("${mongo.db.name}")
    private String MONGO_DB_NAME;

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "test");
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}



**UnitTestFile:**

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.sap.crm.ana.gatewayservice.AnaGatewayServiceApplication;

import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodStarter;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.IMongodConfig;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.Net;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.Version;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Network;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MongoDBConfig.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class CSNHandlerTestEmbeddedMongoDB {

    private CSNHandler handler;
    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private MongoDatabase database;
    private String model;
    private MongodExecutable mongodExecutable;
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        String bindIp = "localhost";
        int port = 27017;
        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
                .net(new Net(bindIp, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6())).build();
        this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(bindIp, port);
        this.database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        mongodExecutable = null;
        try {
            mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
            mongodExecutable.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exception here
            if (mongodExecutable != null)
                mongodExecutable.stop();
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testCSNHandler() throws IOException, ParseException {
        
        handler = new CSNHandler(database);
        handler.insertUpdateAnaModel("100", model);
        
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() throws Exception {
        if (mongodExecutable != null)
            mongodExecutable.stop();
    }
}

**Dependencies:**

<dependency>
<groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
<version>3.12.9</version>
</dependency>
```